# Java sort a csv file based on column date

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, csv

Need to sort a csv file based on the date column. This is how the masterRecords array list looks like

```
GBEP-1-2-4,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 15 2014  - 07:15:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 15 2014  - 07:00:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-2-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 15 2014  - 07:30:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
```

I need to sort it out based from the date 07:15:00, 07:30:00, etc. I created a code to sort it out:

```
// Date is fixed on per 15min interval
ArrayList<String> sortDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortDate.add(":00:");
    sortDate.add(":15:");
    sortDate.add(":30:");
    sortDate.add(":45:");

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempPath + filename));

    for (int k = 0; k < sortDate.size(); k++) {
        String date = sortDate.get(k);
        for (int j = 0; j < masterRecords.size(); j++) {
            String[] splitLine = masterRecords.get(j).split(",", -1);
            if (splitLine[10].contains(date)) {
                bw.write(masterRecords.get(j) + System.getProperty("line.separator").replaceAll(String.valueOf((char) 0x0D), ""));
                masterRecords.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
bw.close();
```

You can see from above it will loop thru a first array (sortDate) and loop thru again  on the second array which is the masterRecord and write it on a new file.  It seems to be working as the new file is sorted out but I notice that my masterRecord has 10000 records but after creating a new file the record shrinks to 5000, Im assuming its how I remove the records from the master list. Anyone knows why?

Comment: are you sure all your date field has only 00-15-30-45? It is possible that there are random time records that got filtered out by the sortDate<> array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is not safe to remove an item inside of a loop. 
You have to iterate array over Iterator, for example:

```
List<String> names = ....
Iterator<String> i = names.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   String s = i.next(); // must be called before you can call i.remove()
   // Do something
   i.remove();
}
```

The documentation says:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Comment: Changing the 2nd loop to iterator made it work. Im now getting the correct number of records. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935539/642706) by [Lautaro Cozzani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4430504/lautaro-cozzani) is correct.

## And Now for Something Completely Different

For fun here is an entirely different approach.

I used two libraries:

- Apache [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)
- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

## Apache Commons CSV

The Commons CSV library handles the parsing of various flavors of CSV. It can return a List of the rows from the file, each row being represented by their `CSVRecord` object. You can ask that object for the first field, second field, and so on.

## Joda-Time

Joda-Time does the work of parsing the date-time strings.

## Avoid 3-letter Time Zone Codes

Beware: Joda-Time refuses to try to parse the three-letter time zone code `MYT`. For good reason: Those 3 or 4 letter codes are mere conventions, neither standardized nor unique. My example code below assumes all your data is using `MYT`. My code assigns the proper time zone name `xxx`. I suggest you enlighten whoever creates your input data to learn about [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and about [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string formats.

## Java 8

My example code requires Java 8, using the new Lambda syntax and "streams".

## Example Code

This example does a double-layer sort. First the rows are sorted by the minute-of-hour (00, 15, 30, 45). Within each of those groups, the rows are sorted by the date-time value (ordered by year, month, day-of-month, and time-of-day).

First we open the .csv text file, and parse its contents into `CSVRecord` objects.

```
String filePathString = "/Users/brainydeveloper/input.csv";
try {
    Reader in = new FileReader( filePathString ); // Get the input file.
    List<CSVRecord> recs = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse( in ).getRecords(); // Parse the input file.
```

Next we wrap those `CSVRecord` objects each inside a smarter class that extracts the two values we care about: first the DateTime, secondly the minute-of-hour of that DateTime. See further down for the simple code of that class `CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute`.

```
    List<CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute> smartRecs = new ArrayList<>( recs.size() ); // Collect transformed data.
    for ( CSVRecord rec : recs ) { // For each CSV record…
        CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute smartRec = new CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute( rec ); // …transform CSV rec into one of our objects with DateTime and minute-of-hour.
        smartRecs.add( smartRec );
    }
```

Next we take that list of our smarter wrapped objects, and break that list into multiple lists. Each new list contains the CSV row data for a particular minute-of-hour (00, 15, 30, and 45). We store these in a map.

If our input data has only occurrences of those four values, the resulting map will have only four keys. Indeed, you can do a sanity-check by looking for more than four keys. Extra keys would mean either something went terribly wrong in parsing or there is some data with unexpected minute-of-hour values.

Each key (the Integer of those numbers) leads to a List of our smart wrapper objects. Here is some of that fancy new Lambda syntax.

```
    Map<Integer , List<CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute>> byMinuteOfHour = smartRecs.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy( CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute::getMinuteOfHour ) );
```

The map does not give us our sub-lists with our keys (minute-of-hour Integers) sorted. We might get back the `15` group before we get the `00` group. So extract the keys, and sort them.

```
    // Access the map by the minuteOfHour value in order. We want ":00:" first, then ":15", then ":30:", and ":45:" last.
    List<Integer> minutes = new ArrayList<Integer>( byMinuteOfHour.keySet() ); // Fetch the keys of the map.
    Collections.sort( minutes ); // Sort that List of keys.
```

Following along that list of ordered keys, ask the map for each key's list. That list of data needs to be sorted to get our second-level sort (by date-time).

```
    List<CSVRecord> outputList = new ArrayList<>( recs.size() ); // Make an empty List in which to put our CSVRecords in double-sorted order.
    for ( Integer minute : minutes ) {
        List<CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute> list = byMinuteOfHour.get( minute );
        // Secondary sort. For each group of records with ":00:" (for example), sort them by their full date-time value.
        // Sort the List by defining an anonymous Comparator using new Lambda syntax in Java 8.
        Collections.sort( list , ( CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute r1 , CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute r2 ) -> {
            return r1.getDateTime().compareTo( r2.getDateTime() );
        } );
        for ( CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute smartRec : list ) {
            outputList.add( smartRec.getCSVRecord() );
        }
    }
```

We are done manipulating the data. Now it is time to export back out to a text file in CSV format.

```
    // Now we have complete List of CSVRecord objects in double-sorted order (first by minute-of-hour, then by date-time).
    // Now let's dump those back to a text file in CSV format.
    try ( PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( "/Users/brainydeveloper/output.csv" ) ) ) ) {
        final CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.print( out );
        printer.printRecords( outputList );
    }

} catch ( FileNotFoundException ex ) {
    System.out.println( "ERROR - Exception needs to be handled." );
} catch ( IOException ex ) {
    System.out.println( "ERROR - Exception needs to be handled." );
}
```

The code above loads the entire CSV data set into memory at once. If wish to conserve memory, use the `parse` method rather than `getRecords` method. At least that is what the doc seems to be saying. I've not experimented with that, as my use-cases so far all fit easily into memory.

Here is that smart class to wrap each `CSVRecord` object:

```
package com.example.jodatimeexperiment;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

/**
 *
 * @author Basil Bourque
 */
public class CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute
{

    // Statics
    static public final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MMM dd yyyy'  - 'hh:mm:ss aa 'MYT'" ).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" ) );

    // Member vars.
    private final CSVRecord rec;
    private final DateTime dateTime;
    private final Integer minuteOfHour;

    public CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute( CSVRecord recordArg )
    {
        this.rec = recordArg;
        // Parse record to extract DateTime.
        // Expect value such as: Dec 15 2014  - 07:15:00 AM MYT
        String input = this.rec.get( 7 - 1 );  // Index (zero-based counting). So field # 7 = index # 6.
        this.dateTime = CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute.FORMATTER.parseDateTime( input );
        // From DateTime extract minute of hour
        this.minuteOfHour = this.dateTime.getMinuteOfHour();
    }

    public DateTime getDateTime()
    {
        return this.dateTime;
    }

    public Integer getMinuteOfHour()
    {
        return this.minuteOfHour;
    }

    public CSVRecord getCSVRecord()
    {
        return this.rec;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "CsvRecWithDateTimeAndMinute{ " + " minuteOfHour=" + minuteOfHour + " | dateTime=" + dateTime + " | rec=" + rec + " }";
    }

}
```

With this input…

GBEP-1-2-4,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 15 2014  - 07:15:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 15 2014  - 07:00:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-2-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 15 2014  - 07:30:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-4,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 14 2014  - 07:15:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 14 2014  - 07:00:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-2-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 14 2014  - 07:30:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-4,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Jan 22 2014  - 07:15:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Jan 22 2014  - 07:00:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-2-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Jan 22 2014  - 07:30:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL

…you will get this output…

GBEP-1-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Jan 22 2014  - 07:00:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 14 2014  - 07:00:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 15 2014  - 07:00:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-4,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Jan 22 2014  - 07:15:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-4,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 14 2014  - 07:15:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-1-2-4,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 15 2014  - 07:15:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-2-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Jan 22 2014  - 07:30:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-2-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 14 2014  - 07:30:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL
GBEP-2-2-1,FRAG,PMTypeEthernet,NEND,TDTN,15-MIN,Dec 15 2014  - 07:30:00 AM MYT,+0,COMPL