# Saving Data from a JavaFX-Application without Database

Tags: java, database, serialization, javafx

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything specific to this topic / to my problem. Here we go:

I'm building a JavaFX Business Application for a friend of mine. Unfortunately I do not have any possibility to connect to a Database. I want the Application to load a savestate from a file. The application contains a list with clients and the clients got some specific properties. I do not want to hardcode this to a .prop or .txt file, because I'm sure that there's a different way of doing this, isn't there?

Thanks in advance, appreciate it!

Comment: Consider presenting a solution (code) or what have you tried so far, before posting a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: What about embedded databases ([e.g. h2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/h2/info))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of choices for persisting data to local storage. The exact choice depends on your needs. You do not describe enough details to make a specific recommendation.

Here is a list of possibilities, roughly in increasing order of complexity of your data.

## Text file

If you have small amounts of simple data, save to a text file. You can store each piece in a separate file, or combine into a single file. Recent versions of Java have new classes to make this easier than ever. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

## Comma-separate & Tab-delimited

For sets of structured data, write to text files in [comma-separated values (CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or [tab-delimited values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values). For example a list of people with rows for each person, and columns for name, phone number, and email address.

While reading/writing such files is easy enough to program yourself, I suggest using an established library to eliminate the drudgery, avoid bugs, and save yourself some time. There are a few such libraries written in Java.

My favorite is the [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) project. This library makes easy work of the chore of reading/writing such files. Despite the name, this library supports tab-delimited as well as comma-separated formats. I've written a few Answers here on Stack Overflow showing how to use this library, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902449/642706), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35569034/642706), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27941613/642706).

By the way, plain old [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) defines a [few character positions explicitly for delimiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text) in data files, with four levels of grouping (document, group, record/row, and field). Unicode, of course, [inherits these from ASCII as code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Control_codes). I am puzzled why these have remained so obscure and so infrequently used. Seems much more logical to me than using commas and tabs which may well exist inside the data payload.

## Serialization

You can write out the data values stored within an object. This is called serialization. Java has a serialization facility built-in, but be sure to study up on the details.

To more simply write out an object’s values and later read them back in to reconstitute an object, I have enjoyed using the [Simple XML Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net) project. This works well for relatively simple needs, and is aimed at the situation where you want the structure of a class to drive the process of determining what to write.

Java has other XML binding facilities both built-in and third-party. These are much more powerful in their flexibility. They are especially good for when you want to define and verify the XML structure in a rigid fashion such as defining a [XML DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) or [XML Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) against which to validate the data and perhaps even generate the Java class in which to represent the data.

## Embedded database

For more complicated data, use an embedded relational database.

The [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database is bundled with many platforms. This is a C-based library, not pure Java. As the name indicates, SQLite is indeed quite “lite“, lacking rigid data types and many other common database features. SQLite is meant to be an alternative to writing text files than as a competitor to more serious databases. It is a great product if your needs fit the sweet-spot of its capabilities.

My first choice for an embedded database would be [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). Built in pure Java. Can be run inside your app, or separately as a server (you choice). Has sophisticated relational database features. Has been around for years, often updated, and is well-worn. The principal author has much experience in the field.